# Como ejecutar funciones en condicional if BASH

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

Estoy tratando de hacer un pequeño script y necesito que los argumentos sean validados para comprobar que estos no estén vacíos.

Tengo muna función que recibe los cuatro argumentos que se le pasan al script mediante un formato de lista.

El problema me viene cuando la función es ejecutada en un if que debe hacer que el script termine debido a un argumento que se la ha pasado vacío. En tal caso la función retorna 1, el condicional lo compara y para la ejecución del script.

## Fragmento del script:

#### Condicional:

```
ARGS=("$FILE" "$POLICYID" "$USERF5" "$PASSWORD")
if [ "$checkArgs ${ARGS[@]}" -eq 1 ]; then
    exit 1
fi
```

#### Función checkArgs:

```
function checkArgs() {
    ARR=("$@")
    for i in "${ARR[@]}"; do
        if [[ -z $i ]]; then
            echo "Missing arguments"
            return 1;
        fi
    done
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/192249/how-do-i-parse-command-line-arguments-in-bash Esta pregunta es muy parecida, quiza pueda resultarte de ayuda

Comment: Los argumentos los tengo parseados ya en otra función pero prefiero hacer el check de cada argumento aparte

Comment: Entonces entiendo que tu problema esta en que hacer un return 1 cuando encuentras un arg vacio en vez de hacer un continue para seguir con las iteraciones. te dejo mas info por si te ayuda:  https://linuxize.com/post/bash-break-continue/

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo bien tu pregunta. Si los argumentos están vacios, entonces **no hay argumentos para asignar al array**, por lo que el "argumento vacío" nunca va a entrar al *for*.

La otra es, si lo que buscas es ver si todos los argumentos que estan en el array, fueron pasados por la consola, lo que se me ocurre es usar awk para encontrar los duplicados:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a required=( uno dos tres )

checkArgs() {
        [ $# -eq 0 ] && echo Missing arguments >&2 && return 1

        matched=$(echo "${required[@]}" "$@" | xargs -n1 | awk 'seen[$0]++' | wc -l)
        [ $matched -ne ${#required[@]} ] && echo Missing arguments >&2 && return 1

        echo All ok
}

checkArgs $@
```

Y correr:

```
$ ./test.sh dos uno tres
All ok
```

Ahora que si quieres que la función devuelva algo al stdout, deberás usar un comando como, digamos, `echo` en lugar de `return`. De esa manera podrás capturar el resultado.

También, hay que diferenciar entre el *exit status* y el *standard output*.

El exit status lo produces con *return*. El standard output lo obtienes con "echo", o algo por el estilo.

Si quieres usar el exit status, puedes usar:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a required=( uno dos tres )

checkArgs() {
        [ $# -eq 0 ] && return 1

        matched=$(echo "${required[@]}" "$@" | xargs -n1 | awk 'seen[$0]++' | awk '!seen[$0]++'| wc -l)
        [ $matched -ne ${#required[@]} ] && return 1

        return 0
}

if checkArgs $@; then
        echo All ok
else
        echo Missing arguments >&2
fi
```

Y el `if` dará un vistazo al exit status de *checkArgs*